# When applying page.mouse() operations in the canvas element, the strokes are not being generated

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

In the latest version of Playwright (1.42), when the browser is set to mobile mode, and I simulate signature functionality on a canvas element by pressing the left mouse button and moving the mouse, no strokes are being generated on the canvas. The canvas board on the website requires being in mobile mode to draw properly.

The code is as follows:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    iphone = playwright.devices["iPhone 12 Pro"]
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    context = browser.new_context(**iphone)
    context.grant_permissions(['camera', 'microphone'])
    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto(
"https://yc-h5-test15.hrfax.cn/ccip/sign/#/?query=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%2FdXVpZD0wZjI0NjQ4ZS01MTkyLTQ3YTEtODAzZi02NWE5ODEwZjIxMDQiLCJzdWNjZXNzVXJsIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly95Yy1oNS10ZXN0MTUuaHJmYXguY24vY2NpcC8jL3BhZ2VzL3NlbGZBcHBseS9yZXN1bHQvaW5kZXg%2FcmVzdWx0PXRydWUmc291cmNlPXNpZ25hdHVyZSIsImZhaWxlZFVybCI6Imh0dHBzOi8veWMtaDUtdGVzdDE1LmhyZmF4LmNuL2NjaXAvIy9wYWdlcy9teU9yZGVyUGFnZS9pbmRleD9mbGFnPWhpc3RvcnlPcmRlciZmcm9tPXNpZ24ifQ%3D%3D")
    page.locator("//uni-view[@Class='btns-box']").click()
    page.wait_for_timeout(3000)
    page.locator("//uni-button").click()
    canvas = page.locator("#canvas")
    canvas_box = canvas.bounding_box()
    center_x = canvas_box['x'] + canvas_box['width'] / 2
    center_y = canvas_box['y'] + canvas_box['height'] / 2
    page.mouse.move(center_x, center_y)
    page.mouse.down(button="left")
    page.mouse.move(center_x, center_y + 100)
    page.mouse.up()
    page.wait_for_timeout(100000)
```

After running the code, there is no stroke appearing on the canvas board in the web page.

The expectation is that when the web page is set to mobile mode, it should be possible to simulate signature actions by smoothly moving the mouse on the canvas board and have the strokes displayed correctly.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. `page.wait_for_load_state("load")` is unnecessary--goto already waits for load.

Comment: Yes, you're right. However, that is not the main focus of the issue. The problem I'm facing is that the strokes are not being displayed on the canvas board.

Comment: No, but clearing away obvious problems makes it easier to focus on the main issue. Looking at the site, I can't replicate any drawing, even in the browser as a user. It's a Chinese (?) site so it's hard to tell what's going on, or if it's even loading for me properly. Maybe someone else can answer.

Comment: Yes, this is a Chinese website, and the canvas board requires switching to mobile mode in order to perform drawing operations. By using F12 to switch to mobile mode in the website, it is possible to perform the drawing operations normally.

Comment: The provided URL in the example is a signature functionality. Upon opening the website, clicking on a button takes you to the end where there is a canvas signature board. This page requires being in mobile mode to draw on the canvas drawing area. As a user, you can switch to mobile mode by pressing F12 and successfully draw on the canvas signature area by moving the mouse.

However, when using Playwright to simulate script execution in mobile mode, it is not possible to draw on the canvas area. Could you please help me understand the reason behind this issue?